# Как СУБД обеспечивает многопользовательское взаимодействие с одним файлом базы данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Мне интересно как огромное количество соединений в итоге работают с одним файлом mdf в случае с sql server? За счет чего достигается параллельность работы с одним файлом? Посоветуйте книги с более детальным описанием работы СУБД.

Comment: Очень просто, с файлом работает только один пользователь — СУБД.

Comment: За счет правильного взаимодействия с CУБД посредством транзакций. Подробнее: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @AlexeyTen означает ли это что все операции происходят последовательно?

Comment: @NoSkill не совсем понял причем тут транзакции? Вопрос в том как физически 2 разных действия одновременно совершаются совершаются с одним файлом.

Comment: 2 разных действия совершаются последовательно в памяти, а результат пишется в файл в определенный момент времени. Одновременность доступа (в общем смысле) к какому либо устройству - это, в большинстве случаев, иллюзия, но тем не менее одновременность физически возможна, когда она гарантировано не угрожает целостности данных (носителя). А вот для целостности данных СУБД есть еще один уровень одновременности доступа, которое приводит к парадигме транзакций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что в случае с базой данных понимание того, как происходит работа с файлами, играет отрицательную роль.

Вам - автору вопроса - кажется, что работа с базой данных - это как работа с файлом, только пользователей много и она работают с файлом одновременно.

Но это не так.

База данных - это программа, которая "одной стороной" торчит в сторону пользователей, а внутри у себя поддерживает работу с файлом.

Когда пользователь делает запрос - он взаимодействует с программой. У программы в памяти есть набор данных. Если запрос относится к этому набору - программа (sql server) отвечает вообще без обращения к файлу.

Если набор данных нужно изменить - то это изменение сначала происходит в памяти, и только потом, в соовтествии с политикой записи в файл, это изменение будет записано. Эта политика может быть настроена так, что запись в файл может быть отложена.

Самое главное - что нет прямого соответствия между обращением к серверу и обращением к файлу.

Есть множество статей по тому, как работают базы данных. Я постарался найти такую, котрая без зубодробительной алгебры и алгоритмов в самом начале - [вот](https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/358984/) вроде неплохая.

Comment: Спасибо. 1) А правильно ли я понимаю что физически запись в файл не может выполнятся параллельно? Т.е. запись в файл отложенно или нет но будет выполнятся последовательно? 2) И еще вопрос т.е. фактически файл нужен как бы грубо говоря только когда СУБД оказалось выключена, а когда она включена большинство информации может находится в оперативке?

Comment: 1) Физически обычно база представлена "страницами". Страница - это, грубо говоря, минимальный "кусочек" базы данных. Обычно с диска читается (и пишется) именно "страница". При записи - чуть чуть хитрее: современные накопители с AHCI и еще более современные NVMA умеют писать параллельно. И теоретически в них можно "выкинуть на запись" несколько "страниц" одновременно. 2) Когда база только "включается - в памяти еще не закешировано страниц данных. По мере выполнения запросов данные перемещается из файла в память. Постепенно - если памяти достаточно - часто импользуемые данные казываются в памяти

Comment: Получается в простом варианте чтение параллельно а запись по очереди? Т.е. два запроса открывают файл на чтение в двух потоках? А если нужна запись тогда уже открывают на запись по очереди?

Comment: Я думаю, что на простом уровне - надо представлять себе так, что на запись открыт файл в одном потоке, а все остальные, кому надо записать - кладут свои запросы "запиши вот эту страницу!" в очередь. А этот единственный поток - вычерпывает запросы из очереди и пишет. В этом смысле - пишет последовательно.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Физический жесткий диск и читать совсем параллельно не может. Если два потока одновременно начнут читать, то ядро ОС само внутри себя держит очереди (или перепоручает жесткому диску), а потоки просто ждут когда им данные отдадут. С записью на низком уровне абсолютно то же самое. Единственная опасность при записи со стороны параллельных потоков, что один может не знать и случайно переписать данные которые только что записал другой. А вот это уже контролирует СУБД на своем уровне, что бы такого не допустить, используя очереди, блокировки и прочие механизмы

Comment: @Mike да у меня как раз такой вопрос тоже был. Т.е. физически если есть условно 10 битов то одновременно их считать все равно не получится в несколько потоков? Но это что касается непосредственно прям одних и тех же битов. А если речь идет об одном файле но разбитом на много разных страниц то считывать разные страницы в несколько потоков реально? или это реально делать параллельно только из оперативной памяти?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Даже доступ к оперативной памяти на железном уровне строго последовательный, шина данных от модулей памяти к процессору одна и передает строго по N бит, согласно своей разрядности. Но параллельные потоки этого не замечают и для них все происходит одновременно. Процессор надежно скрывает эту внутреннюю железную кухню от программ. Просто некоторые команды чтения памяти с точки зрения программы работают чуть медленнее чем другие.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов С дисками то же самое, только от программы внутренности прячет ядро ОС, а не процессор. Два потока и даже две разные программы могут читать один файл одновременно, потому как они вызывают метод чтения ядра ОС и в этот момент ядро приостанавливает работу потока до тех пор, пока данные не будут готовы к передаче ему. Но с точки зрения программиста этого не видно, ибо он сказал в потоке "прочитай" и в следующей строке данные у него есть

Comment: @Mike т.е. если я читаю в один поток с оперативки 100мб я считаю их за такое же примерно время что и в 2 потока параллельно прочитать один файл 50мб ? для меня формально это будет параллельно но на самом деле диск будет по чуть чуть считывать по очереди для двух потоков переключаясь?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Немного не понял вопрос. у вас в начале 100мб оперативки, а потом 50 мб диска. оперативка и диск имеют огромную разницу в скорости работы. Но если 2 потока читают одновременно даже не один файл, а разные файлы, находящиеся на одном физическом диске и при этом отсутствующие в кеше диска ОС, то каждый из них будет работать примерно столько, сколько один поток, читающий 100Мб. А вот если они все таки читают один файл, то все произойдет быстрее, потому что ядро ОС хранит в оперативке данные, которые недавно читала с диска (кеш) и физически прочитает данные один раз

Comment: @Mike да, перепутал. Имел ввиду что да если с диска читаем файл 100мб одним потоком или читаем по 50мб двумя потоками одного файла. А из оперативной памяти такой же принцип? Т.е. мы можем получить ускорения за счет того что у нас один поток физически читает с диска, а в второй с кеша ОС. Тогда остался вопрос, а если будет третий поток ускорения уже не будет? т.е. в таком случае потоки 2 и 3 которые буду считывать данные уже не с диска, а с оперативки будут между собой последовательно считывать? Т.е. такой же принцип будет что из оперативки 2 потока 50мб считывают как один 100?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов про какие 50 Мб речь, если все потоки читают одни и те же 50Мб то они это выполняют в среднем со скоростью чтения 50Мб с диска, так как с диска ОС читает один раз и раздает всем, кому нужны эти блоки данных. А если потоки читают разные 50 Мб, даже из одного файла (один сначала, другой с середины), то оба будут медленнее, потому что ОС действительно может читать небольшими кусками (обычно 4 Кб) то для одного то для другого

Comment: @Mike с диском понял да, спасибо. Речь уже была про ОЗУ если мне нужно прочитать одни и те же данные в 2+ потоках, будет поочередное считывание? И вы пишите ОС раздает кому нужно, раздает так же поочередно т.е. если у меня 5 потоков, мы один раз прочитали с диска но дальше так же будет раздавать поочередно?

Comment: @ПавелКозлов ОС тут не причем. этим всем заведует процессор. И все гораздо сложнее. Во первых у каждого ядра процессора есть собственный кеш, примерно как кеш диска, только для оперативки. Во вторых у процессора есть очередь предчтения, которая заполняет кеш для будущих выполняемых команд заранее. В третьих в программе обычно перемешаны команды доступа к данным с другими командами. И пока работает команда без доступа к данным, процессор для следующей, с доступом, данные по шине протащит в кеш. В четвертых это наносекунды.

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Так что чисто теоретически, в идеальных условиях, если два потока выполняют абсолютно одинаковый код с интенсивным доступом к памяти, при отсутствии переключения задач на ядрах, при условии что выполнение кода обоих потоков синхронизировано с точностью до команды, то каждый из них будет заметно медленнее из за того что память будет не успевать и ее ресурсы будут делиться между потоками. Но на практике упереться по скорости именно в память могут редкие, специфические задачи

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123435/discussion-between---and-mike).

Comment: ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ все задачи выполняются последовательно (хоть и кажется, что выполняются одновременно). С целью оптимизации задача может быть разбита на части, которые могут выполнятся паралельно как на физическом, так и на логическом уровне, но собраны эти части воедино В КАКОЙ-ТО МОМЕНТ будут так, чтобы это не угрожало целостности данных. Важно понять одну вешь: вычислительная паралельность и одновременность выполнения на самом деле понятия совершенно разные. Если 100 паралельно выполняющихся потоков обратятся к одним и тем-же данным "одновременно", то ОС сделает такой доступ последовательным.